# MaterializeCSS - SideNav events not triggering properly

Tags: javascript, html, materialize, sidenav

I have a basic html-page with a navbar ([Navbar Documentation](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#mobile-collapse)) and a collapsible sidenav ([SideNav Documentation](http://materializecss.com/sidenav.html)).
The sidenav itself works fine but the "onOpenStart" and "onEndClose" events both trigger as soon as the page is done loading and not when the sidenav opens/closes.

I guess an alternative would be to hook some events on the sidenav-trigger and go from there but that seems quite unneccessary if these events already exist.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gvgo2Lu2/2/
Any help would be appreciated

HTML

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
          <a href="#" data-target="mobile-nav" class="sidenav-trigger">
            <i id="test" class="material-icons">menu</i>
          </a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
              <a href="#!">Link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- MOBILE NAV -->
  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#!">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

JS

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
var instance = M.Sidenav.init(elem, {
  onOpenStart: console.log("I trigger as soon as the page is loaded"),
  onCloseEnd: console.log("same")
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation the **onOpenStart** and **onCloseEnd** events need a callback function. But, you are using the result of a computation: console.log(....). Because that value is undefined you are not adding the event handlers!

In order to overcome the issue you need to change your init to (updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvgo2Lu2/5/)):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
var instance = M.Sidenav.init(elem, {
    onOpenStart: function () {
        console.log("I trigger as soon as the page is loaded");
    },
    onCloseEnd: function () {
        console.log("same");
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <a href="#!" data-target="mobile-nav" class="sidenav-trigger">
                    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                </a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- MOBILE NAV -->
<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#!">Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```